# How to only show the paths of Greace Pencil strokes?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, grease-pencil, path

I accidentally inputted a shortcut while drawing in a Greace Pencil object and now only the paths of the strokes are shown.

Now I'm curious about **what key combination** it was and **how to leave this view**.

I believe it was `Ctrl + T` (unfortunately I cannot test this because I stuck in the path-only view).

Here is an example:

[image]

I'm using Blender v2.83.2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the hiding of the strokes goes, I have found a solution:

For whatever reason, the wireframe view was selected.
This problem was solved by selecting any other view in the top right corner (e.g. Solid view).

[image]